# Use node.js (with express) as static webserver

Tags: node.js, webserver, express

I'm looking to use node.js with express to create a Webserver that serves static files (as opposed to using something like Apache).  This is what I have so far:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
    app.use(app.router);
});

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(4001);
```

This works in that anything placed in the public folder can be accessed via browser.  I have two questions though.

1. How do I make it so that node.js will provide a 404 error when a user tries to access a non-existent file?
2. How would I then select my homepage?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at existing implementations like [ecstatic](https://github.com/jesusabdullah/node-ecstatic) and [http-server](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server).

Answer (score 0):

you can have a homepage using a `/public/index.html` file
you can create a 404 page by adding after `app.router`

```
app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.send(404, 'File not found.')
})
```

or you can use `res.render` or whatever you'd like.